# conditional unique constraint on multiple columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with three columns - c_id, o_id, f_id. The combination of the three ids has to be unique as long as f_id is not 3.

After reading similar questions I tried the following :

```
create unique index my_index on my_table (
decode (f_id, !3, c_id, null),
decode (f_id, !3, o_id, null),
decode (f_id, !3, f_id, null));
```

but I'm getting a *missing expression* error. I also tried with

```
create unique index my_index on my_table ((
case 
when f_id <> 3 then c_id
when f_id <> 3 then o_id
when f_id <> 3 then f_id
else null
end));
```

but for this one I'm getting *cannot create index; duplicate keys found*

Originally I tried

```
when f_id <> 3 then (c_id, o_id, f_id)
```

but that didn't work at all.

Anyhow, something is probably wrong with the index as the table doesn't seem to have any duplicates, I get no records with

```
select c_id, o_id, f_id, count(*) as dupes
from my_table
where f_id <> 3
having count(*) > 1
group by c_id, o_id, f_id;
```

I'm kinda running blind with these FBIs, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a 3-part index:

```
create unique index my_index
    on my_table (case when f_id <> 3 then c_id end,
                 case when f_id <> 3 then o_id end,
                 case when f_id <> 3 then f_id end
                );
```

Comment: This works. However, it will also allow duplicate combos of `(c_id,o_id)` when `f_id` is null (which is different to how a compound unique key normally behaves).

Comment: It seems to be working. I'll accept it as soon as I do some more testing. Would you be so kind as to explain what is the difference between 3-part index and the incorrect case I was using?

Comment: @tom - Your version of the CASE solution only indexes a single column because it has one CASE statement. That's why you get Duplicate Value exceptions. Gordon's solution has three CASE statements, one for each column you want to index,

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach with only one column index:

```
create unique index all_but_3 on tst (case when nvl(f_id,0) != 3 then o_id||'.'||c_id||'.'||f_id end);
```

Test

```
insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(3,3,3);
insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(3,3,3); -- OK

insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(3,3,2);
insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(3,3,2); -- ORA-00001: unique constraint  xxx violated

insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(3,3,null);
insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(3,3,null); -- ORA-00001: unique constraint  xxx violated

insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(null,null,2);
insert into tst(c_id, o_id, f_id) values(null,null,2); -- -- ORA-00001: unique constraint  xxx violated
```